# How to update miniconda and Spyder 4.2.1

Tags: python, spyder, miniconda

When I opened Spyder, I saw a message of

```
Spyder 4.2.1 is available! Instead, run the following commands in a terminal 
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=4.2.1"
```

I installed miniconda before, so I opened anaconda prompt, then type in

```
conda update anaconda

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\yongn\miniconda3
  package name: anaconda
```

then I switched to

```
conda update miniconda
```

and I got same error:

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\yongn\miniconda3
  package name: miniconda
```

any suggestion on how to update miniconda?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$ conda update conda

conda is the package manager. Anaconda is the big enchilada with >100 packages included.

Comment: Thanks rilabs. It works. I thought conda is like pip